# NoClassDefFoundError using Libgdx

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, google-play-services

I started a libgdx project about a year ago but recently I tried adding the gdx-pay library to it, this wouldn't work so someone on here suggested remaking the project and updating my libraries. Now gdx-pay seems to import correctly but I can't get the rest of my project to work anymore. I've been trying for a month now so I forget most of what I've tried but I tried remaking the project 3 times and linking google play services multiple different ways both using gradle and without. I've had several different errors but using my current project I am getting the NoClassDefFoundError. I have attached the error portion of my logcat log below.

> 03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331): Process: com.FF7Squirrelman.game.android, PID: 13331
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.(Unknown Source)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.(Unknown Source)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.createApiClientBuilder(GameHelper.java:279)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.setup(GameHelper.java:326)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at com.FF7Squirrelman.game.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:90)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.FF7Squirrelman.game.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.FF7Squirrelman.game.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    ... 18 more
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):        ... 19 more
>   03-15 04:15:17.454: E/AndroidRuntime(13331):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

any idea what could be causing this? Everything is updated via my android sdk manager except basegameutils which I downloaded elsewhere. Google play service libs and basegameutils are both checked as libraries, basegameutils has google play services libs linked as a android reference and both basegameutils. Google play services libs are linked to the android launcher as android references.

Comment: Try using Eclipse Kepler instead of Mars...not sure if that's your issue but I know Eclipse Mars doesn't deal well with the libgdx gradle file